# SSH: How to disable password authentication?

Tags: linux, ssh

I created a pub/pri key combo with putty. In putty I can set where the private key is, and login that way. BUT if I dont set my pri key , the server still asks for my password and lets me login. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a *nix server (which would be good info to have), modify the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, setting `PasswordAuthentication` to `no`.

Comment: ...and restart SSHD.